# Manually reorder tabs in PhpStorm with keyboard

Tags: phpstorm, keymapping, phpstorm-2017.1

I am in the process of migrating from Sublime Text 3 to PhpStorm and want to replicate as many of my old keyboard shortcuts as possible.

One that I used in ST3 with the aid of a plugin was the ability to shuffle my open tabs around with a keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + PageUp/PageDown</kbd>) to nudge the currently open tab left or right.

PhpStorm allows tabs to be manually reordered by dragging and dropping with the mouse, but as far as I can see, there is no any relevant command in the keymap settings.

Anyone know if this is achievable?

Answer (score 1):

There are few tickets on "activate/move editor tabs with keyboard only" subject. For example:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-133403
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68324
- etc

---

AFAIK there is no built-in functionality that can do it .. but it can be done by some plugins.

**"A move tab left and right using the keyboard plugin - by momomo"** -- sounds like exact match (have not tested myself).

---

Related plugins:

- GoToTabs plugin -- for activating specific editor tab (first 10 tabs) just like in Chrome/Firefox browsers (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl + 1</kbd>)
- Close Editor Tabs Left Right
- Tab Shifter

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Quite possibly the first plugin (momomo) does what I want. Only thing is- and I assume I'm missing something really obvious here- I've installed the plugin but I've no idea how to use it. The author neglects to mention *what the keyboard shortcuts for moving tabs actually are*. AFAICS no new options have appeared in the keymap settings, and blind trial-and-error has been unfruitful. So I'm no better off....

Comment: Check it in Keymap under "Plug-ins" node -- if anything they should be listed there under that plugin sub-node.

Comment: Yeah, I looked there- nothing :|

Comment: Well .. from plugin meta file -- `Shift+Ctrl+PgDown/PgUp` .... but they do not do anything (looks like they are not getting registered at all -- maybe plugin is no longer compatible?) No other ideas unfortunately.